# How to place Jbuttons at a desired location and change colour between them?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I am trying to place four buttons in the following order, but the buttons are sticking to the top and I want them to be placed at a different location.

Here is my code:

```
{
    JLabel back = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\file\\Desktop\\background.png"));

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 80, 15));
    p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0));

    add(back);
    back.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    p1.add(jbtstart);
    p1.add(jbtabout);
    p1.add(jbtcredits);
    p1.add(jbtexit);
    back.add(p1);

    jbtstart.addActionListener(this);
    jbtabout.addActionListener(this);
    jbtcredits.addActionListener(this);
    jbtexit.addActionListener(this);

    setContentPane(back);

    setTitle("Cooking App");
    setSize(300, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

What have I to do?

Comment: what are the locations? e.g. north, south, east, west? You can try out different layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to read GridLayout documentation:
[Read more about GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
[Read more about MouseListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) (for changing colors)

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried BorderLayout?

```
    back.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

And:

```
    back.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

PS: Why do you set the size and pack after?

```
setSize(300, 250);
pack();
```

There is something twice.